# Как в WM_CREATE получить имя, заданное окну при создании?

Tags: c++, winapi, callback

Создаётся окно:

```
MainWindow = CreateWindowExW(
            WS_EX_TOPMOST,
            MainWindowClass.lpszClassName,
            L"Test Player",
            WS_POPUPWINDOW | SW_HIDE,
            0,0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
            nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

В обработчике WM_CREATE хочу сделать трей-меню с соответствующим именем ("Test Player" в данном случае):

```
case WM_CREATE:{
            if( Menu ) break;
            HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongW(hWnd,GWL_HINSTANCE);
            Menu = CreatePopupMenu();

            int size = 24;
            wchar_t name[size];
            memset(name,0,size);
            GetWindowTextW(hWnd,name,size);
            wprintf(L"%ls / %d\n",name,GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd)); // T / 1

            memset(&Tray, 0, sizeof (NOTIFYICONDATAW));
            Tray.cbSize = sizeof(Tray);
            Tray.hWnd = hWnd;
            Tray.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_INFO;
            Tray.uCallbackMessage = WM_TRAY_MENU;
            Tray.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICO_MAIN));
            wcscpy(Tray.szTip, name);
            Shell_NotifyIconW(NIM_ADD, &Tray);
```

Но через `GetWindowText` получаю только первую букву "T", соответственно и длину имени показывает в 1 символ при консольном выводе `GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd)`. Это имя будет динамическим, в зависимости от параметров инициализации приложения, поэтому делать его глобальным нельзя.

Как правильно получить имя окна в колбеке?

[UPDATE]

Кириллицу читает нормально, латиницу - нет. В уведомления могут посылаться разные комбинации символов, как типа `A`, так и `W`

Comment: @Abyx, нет. Проблема в функции `GetWindowTextW`, которая именно в W версии отказывается читать имя окна в ASCII. Первую букву считывает и всё. Русский текст считывает корректно.

Comment: `wchar_t name[size];` является невалидным выражением в С++, так как размер не является константой времени компиляции. А вообще пример какой-то странный. Чем это собирается? Почему содержимое буфера проверяется через печать (printf-отладка - зло)?

Comment: В VS 2017 все работает, если добавить const к объявлению массива. Вот код: https://gist.github.com/MSDN-WhiteKnight/ee7b70d7705bd1c0994fe6118a8d3ca5 Выводит "Test Player / 11"

Comment: @VTT, собирается g++ из WinGW-w64-i686. "printf-отладка - зло" - согласен, не самый удобный вариант, а Вы как отлаживаете?

Comment: тестами и ассертами

Comment: "*В уведомления могут посылаться разные комбинации символов, как типа A, так и W*" - поясните эту часть. Вы пытаетесь как-то комбинировать ANSI и Unicode? Это вообще-то не работает. Класс окна использует либо ANSI, либо Unicode (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexa#remarks), это жестко задается при его создании.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, поясняю - например вывод, содержащий и русский текст и английский, вроде "Запуск Test Player...". Я понимаю, что кодировка жёстко задаётся, и если там предполагается юникод, то создать надо W. Но в этом случает почему-то не работает получение имени. Ваш вариант почему-то не сработал. Пока решил костылём через глобальную переменную-буфер, без вызова GetWindowText

Comment: @Iceman А вы уверены, что не работает именно получение текста? С той же вероятностью может "не работать" и установка. Вы пробовали включить заголовок у окна и посмотреть, что в нем выводится? "*Ваш вариант почему-то не сработал*" - если мой код (в точности) не сработал, это похоже на баг компилятора. Я не вижу, других причин, чтобы он не работал.

Comment: может размер wchar_t неправильный? вставьте `static_assert(2 == sizeof(wchar_t));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `const int size = 24;`
2) `memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));` у вас memset занулит только половину массива, т.к. ожидает размер в байтах.
3) **Project** -> **Properties** -> **General**: **Character Set** изменить на **Use Unicode Character Set** вместо Multi-byte